# mysql select join with 2 different ORDER BY's

Tags: mysql

I have written this select

```
SELECT
  t1.id t1_id, t1.title t1_title, t1.subtitle t1_subtitle, t1.content t1_content,
  t3.picture t3_picture

FROM
  webcms_cms_content t1

INNER JOIN webcms_mod_galleries_pictures t3
  ON t1.gallery_id = t3.gallery_id

WHERE t1.structure_id =3
AND t1.status=1
AND t1.flag=1
ORDER BY t1.newsdatum DESC
```

and this little php snippet:

```
$i=0;
while($db->next_record()) {
    $con[$db->get_content('t1_id')]['id']           = $db->get_content('t1_id');
    $con[$db->get_content('t1_id')]['title']        = $db->get_content('t1_title');
    $con[$db->get_content('t1_id')]['link']         = $db->get_content('t1_subtitle');
    $con[$db->get_content('t1_id')]['content']      = $db->get_content('t1_content');
    $con[$db->get_content('t1_id')]['pics'][$i]     = $db->get_content('t3_picture');
    $i++;
}
```

which returns me an array like this:

```
array
    8 => 
        array
            'id' => string '8' (length=1)
            'title' => string 'Studios (2 Personen)' (length=20)
            'link' => string '350.- bis 550.- ' (length=16)
            'content' => string 'Gem&uuml;tlich eichenm&ouml;biliertes Studio bestehend aus einem Wohnraum mit zwei Schrankbetten, Fernseher mit Radio, Telefon, Wireless, K&uuml;che mit Backofen, Wasserkocher und Kaffeemaschine, Bad/Dusche, WC und auf der S&uuml;dseite mit Terasse und Matterhornblick.' (length=269)
            'pics' => 
                array
                    0 => string 'p186rgot3ohd612pljp8m8h12d74' (length=28)
                    1 => string 'p186rgot3o1cso2nj4h81e47ils2' (length=28)
                    2 => string 'p186rgl7f84r9h671jkr1vctip61' (length=28)
                    3 => string 'p186rgot3o6fjk7c1j1nc1p1ukj1' (length=28)
                    4 => string 'p186rhu0bjuq9tfe1ca13ll1qte1' (length=28)
```

Soo now this is ok but I want much more :) Don't know if this is possible (this is the first bigger sql query I write).

1. there is one "element" missing cause that one hasn't got any entries in t3.picture

1.1 so I want the pics array just to be empty

1. I need to ORDER BY t1.newsdatum DESC AND ORDER BY t3.rang ASC

Is this possible in just one query? With multiple querys no problem but I would love to have only one.

Created a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1b86/8)

Thanks in advance for your time and suggestions!

Comment: It will be more useful to split your requirements one by one. Solving all your needs at once is long and tedious. And useless for the rest of the users.

Comment: If you have a new problem, post a new question (and mark this as answered, if it has been answered.) Don't edit the question with new requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a LEFT OUTER JOIN to get the rows where there is no matching row on the other table:-

```
SELECT t1.id AS t1_id, 
        t1.title AS t1_title, 
        t1.subtitle AS t1_subtitle, 
        t1.content AS t1_content,
        t3.picture AS t3_picture
FROM webcms_cms_content t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN webcms_mod_galleries_pictures t3
ON t1.gallery_id = t3.gallery_id
WHERE t1.structure_id = 3
AND t1.status = 1
AND t1.flag = 1
ORDER BY t1.newsdatum DESC, t3.rang ASC
```

Then some php to populate your array:-

```
$prev_id = 0;
while($db->next_record()) 
{
    if ($prev_id != $db->get_content('t1_id'))
    {
        $con[$db->get_content('t1_id')]['id']       = $db->get_content('t1_id');
        $con[$db->get_content('t1_id')]['title']    = $db->get_content('t1_title');
        $con[$db->get_content('t1_id')]['link']     = $db->get_content('t1_subtitle');
        $con[$db->get_content('t1_id')]['content']  = $db->get_content('t1_content');
        $con[$db->get_content('t1_id')]['pics']     = array();
        $prev_id = $db->get_content('t1_id');
    }
    $con[$db->get_content('t1_id')]['pics'][]     = $db->get_content('t3_picture');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try "ORDER BY t1.newsdatum DESC, t3.rang ASC"?